# Axios Interceptor is not working in React JS

Tags: reactjs, axios, interceptor, refresh-token, response-headers

I am using the below code as an **interceptor** in my React JS app for getting token back but unfortunately, it is not working. Refresh token returns new idToken and updates local storage data correctly. The same code I'm using some other application which works fine. One main difference is that **I currently use React 18 and the previous 16**. I struggled to identify the problem but failed. Your help will be appreciable.

```js
axios.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => {
    return response;
  },
  (error) => {
    if (error.response.status === 401) {
      // console.log(error.response.data.code)
      let usersData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userData"));
      const refreshToken = usersData.refreshToken;
      return axios
        .post(
          `${api_base_url}/auth/authentication/refresh_token`,
          JSON.stringify({
            refresh_token: refreshToken,
          })
        )
        .then((response) => {
          usersData["accessToken"] = response.data.data.accessToken;
          usersData["idToken"] = response.data.data.idToken;

          setSessionStorage("userData", usersData);

          error.response.config.headers[
            "Authorization"
          ] = `Bearer ${response.data.data.idToken}`;

          return axios(error.response.config);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          if (error.response.data.code !== "TOKEN_EXPIRED") {
            return;
          }
          localStorage.clear();
          window.location = "/login";
        });
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);
```

```
function getIRequestProp(severType, isMultipart, isSocial) {
    const serverUrl = severType ? social_api_base_url : api_base_url;
    let userData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData'));
    let idToken;
    idToken = userData !== null ? userData['idToken'] : '';
    let content_type;
    if (isSocial) {
        content_type = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    } else {
        content_type = isMultipart ? 'multipart/form-data' : 'application/json'
    }

    return {
        serverUrl: serverUrl,
        requestHeader: {
            'Content-Type': content_type,
            'Accept-Language': DEFAULT_LANGUAGE,
            Authorization: `Bearer ${idToken}`
        }
    };
}

async function post(url, body, isSocialServer, isMultipart) {
    const {serverUrl, requestHeader} = getIRequestProp(isSocialServer, isMultipart);
    return axios.post(serverUrl + url, body, {
        headers: requestHeader
    });
}
```

So, I call API like this:

```
   AxiosServices.post(ApiUrlServices.SOCIALS_UPDATE_LINKS(UserInfo.userId), payload, false)
        .then(response => {})
```

What i figured out that `return axios(error.response.config);` is not sending authorization token in API request headers and trying request infinitely. But consoling `error.response.config` shows token sets in the config correctly.

Comment: Remove the `JSON.stringify()`, just pass a plain object so Axios knows to set the appropriate content-type header

Comment: Removed. Still same issues.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to match. What data format does the `refresh_token` endpoint expect. Usually they want `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, not `application/json`

Comment: I already mentioned: "What i figured out that return axios(error.response.config); is not sending authorization token in API request headers and trying request infinitely. But consoling error.response.config shows token sets in the config correctly." Refresh token API works fine.

Comment: What version of Axios are you using?

Comment: return axios(error.response.config); this line does not send the newly received idToken in the new request. localstorage also sets with newly received idToken

Comment: Axios version : 1.1.3

Comment: Do you have any request interceptors configured? How is the token usually added to requests? Presumably you retrieve it from session storage (or wherever `setSessionStorage()` writes to). Please [edit] your question

Comment: No interceptor was configured. imported axios by: import axios from 'axios';

Comment: What does your debugging tell you? You could add something like `console.log("tokens", response.data.data.idToken, response.data.data.accessToken)` to make sure you're actually getting the values you expect

Comment: It gives output like "tokens eyJraWQiOiJUc1FBdDRoU29oeis5V0g4WU9Ua3AxY1ZcL1ZSck............"

Comment: Are you sure `idToken` is the correct bearer token to be using and not `accessToken`? I really can't see anything else wrong here at all. The only way this enters an infinite loop is if the API continues to respond with a 401 error. You can ultimately check the headers sent using your browser's dev-tools _Network_ panel. If the token is definitely the new `idToken`, then the problem must be the token itself

Comment: 100% sure. If i console error.response.config it also shows that newly fetched idToken also sets for new request in the config. And "return axios(error.response.config);" this line doesn't work and falls into continuous loop. Checked headers from network which does not send Authorization token.

Comment: No, I find the headers using {error.response.config} not {error.config}. I think problem solved adding additional configuration of axios request. Adding my solution

Comment: Looks like this is just an(other) Axios bug. The headers aren't being serialised properly. Reproduced here ~ https://jsfiddle.net/4Lnckzjp/. Apparently it's fixed in v1.2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding an additional modification of axios request, I solved my problem.

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(request => {
    // Edit request config
    let usersData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData'));
    request.headers['Authorization'] = `${usersData.idToken}`;
    return request;
}, error => {
    return Promise.reject(error);
});
```

Comment: You're missing the `Bearer` prefix

Comment: That's not mandatory in my case. :)